# Password protect a program without system accounts

Tags: access-control, account-restrictions

we have a Linux system with a program to control a machine. We want to restrict and log access to this program with some kind of user/password combination, but I don't want to create a new user account for each person who is allowed to use the program.

Is there some kind of (shell)-tool which asks for a username and password and then starts another program and logs the time the users uses the program?

I don't really expect the users to try to bypass the system so I don't really need a way to stop them from starting the machine control program directly. I would just replace the desktop link with the new tool.

Any ideas if a tool like this exists or do I have to write it on my own?

Thanks
Dirk

Comment: Why don't you create a new group into which you add the existing users that are allowed to start the program? Then change the permissions on the program som that only members of the group can execute it. This way you don't need to create a new account for every user. For logging you could write a wrapper program that does the logging and starts the program.

Comment: Building on Johan's idea, you could also use File ACLs, to add execution privileges to only your new group, leaving the original permissions intact. As far as best practices are concerned though, I believe this to be less than ideal.